# sort a date which is inside mutable array of dictionaries

Tags: iphone

Would it be possible for someone to make a tutorial on how to sort a date which is inside mutable array of dictionaries ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your NSDate object is in a dictionary with @"DateKey" key.

```
NSInteger dateSort(id dict1, id dict2, void* context){
    return [[dict1 objectForKey:@"DateKey"] compare:[dict2 objectForKey:@"DateKey"]];
}

[dateArray sortUsingFunction:dateSort context:NULL];
```

Or iOS 4 solution:

```
[dateArray sortUsingComparator:(NSComparator)^(id obj1, id obj2){
    return [[obj1 objectForKey:@"DateKey"] compare:[obj1 objectForKey:@"DateKey"]];
    }];
```

The following line should sort NSMutableArray containing NSDate objects:

```
[dateArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Comment: The OP appears to be sorting an `NSMutableArray` of `NSDictionary` objects, each containing an `NSDate`.  A custom comparison method is required.

Comment: @Justin, thanks, read the question too fast and missed its point.